# What is the mcrypt_get_block alternative and how to use it

Tags: php, wordpress, symfony, encryption

I have an old wordpress plugin built using symfony framework and which uses `mcrypt_get_block_size('tripledes', 'ecb')`. However, I have just upgraded php on my server to version 7.3 and now I am getting a `Fatal error: Call to undefined function HealthShieldForm\mcrypt_encrypt()`.

I have read few articles where they suggest using `openssl_encrypt()`. Unfortunately I dont know where to begin in terms of replacing the functions with eachother and insure I am getting the same results.

My current code is this:

```
private function encrypt($data)
    {
        //Pad for PKCS7
        $blockSize = mcrypt_get_block_size('tripledes', 'ecb');
        $len = strlen($data);
        $pad = $blockSize - ($len % $blockSize);
        $data .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);

        //Encrypt data
        $encData = mcrypt_encrypt('tripledes', $this->key, $data, 'ecb');

        return base64_encode($encData);
    }

    private function decrypt($data)
    {
        $data = base64_decode($data);

        $data = mcrypt_decrypt('tripledes', $this->key, $data, 'ecb');

        $block = mcrypt_get_block_size('tripledes', 'ecb');
        $len = strlen($data);
        $pad = ord($data[$len - 1]);

        return substr($data, 0, strlen($data) - $pad);
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I have adapted Peter's example to reflect on my code:

```
function encrypt($data)
    {
        $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($data, 'des-ede3-ecb', $this->key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
        return base64_encode($ciphertext);
    }

    function decrypt($data)
    {
        $ciphertext = base64_decode($data);
        $plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, 'des-ede3-ecb', $this->key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
        return $plaintext;
    }
```

However, now I am getting this error: `Warning: openssl_encrypt(): Unknown cipher algorithm`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this may be the perfect opportunity to update your crypto. Triple DES is generally fine, but pretty much only used because it can be implemented very efficiently in hardware (such as smart cards). For servers and PCs and such AES has equal if not better performance characteristics (modern CPUs have special instructions for AES due to its ubiquitous use in TLS).

Do not use ECB if you can help it, no matter which block cipher you choose. [You can see penguins through it](https://blog.filippo.io/the-ecb-penguin/).

If you are free to choose, use [libsodium](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sodium.php) and pick one of [the AEAD constructions](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/secret-key_cryptography/aead) (the PHP docs are pretty much non-existant, but you can fairly easily correlate the official docs with the matching wrapper functions in PHP).

In can only recommend against using OpenSSL (it has countless sharp edges; won't even tell you if your key is too short, for instance), but in case you insist on rolling with it:

OpenSSL does not have a function that returns the block size for a given cipher. However, you also don't need it here because openssl_encrypt applies PKCS#7 by default:

```
function encrypt(string $plaintext, string $key): string 
{
    $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, 'des-ede3-ecb', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
    return base64_encode($ciphertext);
}

function decrypt(string $ciphertext64, string $key): string 
{
    $ciphertext = base64_decode($ciphertext64)
    $plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, 'des-ede3-ecb', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
    return $plaintext;
}
```

Comment: i have adapted your code to reflect on my code like so:
`
function encrypt($data)
    {
        $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($data, 'des-ede3-ecb', $this->key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
        return base64_encode($ciphertext);
    }

    function decrypt($data)
    {
        $ciphertext = base64_decode($data);
        $plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, 'des-ede3-ecb', $this->key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
        return $plaintext;
    }
`

Comment: Try `des-ede` without the `-ecb`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using ECB with PKCS#5 / 7 padding (not explicitly mentioned, but that's the padding that is manually applied). That padding is the default for OpenSSL, so you just have to use `'des-ede3'` without `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` and `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` as options.

The only other problem that I see is if the key is too small or big. In that case the mcrypt lib will pad with zero bytes or prune the rightmost bytes. So you may need to do this yourself if encryption / decryption fails.

Good luck, and try and move away from this terrible protocol and code ASAP.

Comment: to be honest, i am not familiar with any of those protocols and what they do, i am just trying to update a legacy code that was inherited from a previous developer.